# Variable must be initialized Kotlin numbers

Tags: kotlin, initialization, int

At first i ask user about his marks in school. He choose school subject and then write a mark from last exam. I want summarize in the end od program and add commentary. But the problem is "Variable must be initialized" can you help me?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var Math_mark: Int
    var Biology_mark: Int
    var school_subject: String

    println("Choose school subject: math or biology")
    school_subject = readLine()!!.toString().toUpperCase()
    if (school_subject == "MATH") {
           println("Choose your last exam mark: ")
        Math_mark = readLine()!!.toInt()

    }
if (school_subject == "BIOLOGY"){
    println("Choose your last exam mark: ")
    Biology_mark = readLine()!!.toInt()
}

    println("Your results:")
    if (Math_mark > 2) {
    println("Good boi")
    }
    else{
        println("Bad boi")
    }
    if (Biology_mark > 2){
        println("Good boi")
    }
    else{
        println("Bad boi")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin doesn't allow uninitialized variables, so you have to initialize them with default values:

```
var Math_mark: Int = 0
var Biology_mark: Int = 0
var school_subject: String = ""
```