# Variable must be initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a typealias like:
typealias FetchCompletionHandler = (FetchResponse?, FetchError?) -> Unit
which I have to pass to a function as an argument but I'm getting an error that "Variable must be initialized".
I've declared the variable as following:
val fetchCompletionHandler: FetchCompletionHandler

Comment: Your variable declaration needs an `=` followed by the value that will be stored in it.

Comment: Can you post your formatted exact code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable must be initialized Kotlin numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777076/variable-must-be-initialized-kotlin-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

To use `fetchCompletionHandler` you need to initialize it with a lambda function

```
val fetchCompletionHandler: FetchCompletionHandler = {response, error ->
  //handle response or error here

}
```

to invoke `fetchCompletionHandler`

```
fetchCompletionHandler(response, error)
```